# How to display a value from collection of collections in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an entity called Requests that is a parent to another entity called RequestDetails. Now RequestDetails consist of things like quantity, fees, and also product which points to another entity called products in the system. I have everything set up that saving works perfectly meaning only generic information go to the Request entity when RequestDetail consist of more granular information and the product_id that can connect to the Product entity.

Now when I want to display the data, everything shows up besides the product data. Also, when I dump the {{dump(detail.product)}} in my view it shows the right structure of the product entity however when I try to do something like {{dump(detail.product.name)}} it doesn't work. How do I approach this problem? How do I display in my view? Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Here is my code:

My view:

```
<tbody>
                    {% for request in requests %}
                    <tr class="gradeX">
                        <td>{{request.name}}</td>
                        {% for detail in request.details %}
                        <td>
                            {{dump(detail.product)}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        {{ detail.quantity }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        ${{ detail.pricePerUnit }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        ${{ detail.shippingCost }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        ${{ detail.otherFees }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        ${{ detail.quantity * detail.pricePerUnit + detail.shippingCost + detail.otherFees }}
                        </td>
                        {% endfor %}

                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}

                    </tbody>
```

RequestForEstimate entity:

```
<?php

namespace SourcingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * RequestForEstimate
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="request_for_estimate")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SourcingBundle\Repository\RequestForEstimateRepository")
 */
class RequestForEstimate
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="request_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="create_time", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createTime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="update_time", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updateTime;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RequestForEstimateDetail", mappedBy="detail", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $details;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->details = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param integer $status
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimate
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set createTime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createTime
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimate
     */
    public function setCreateTime($createTime)
    {
        $this->createTime = $createTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createTime
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreateTime()
    {
        return $this->createTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set updateTime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updateTime
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimate
     */
    public function setUpdateTime($updateTime)
    {
        $this->updateTime = $updateTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updateTime
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdateTime()
    {
        return $this->updateTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimate
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Add detail
     *
     * @param \SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimateDetail $detail
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimate
     */
    public function addDetail(\SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimateDetail $detail)
    {
        $this->details->add($detail);
        $detail->setDetail($this);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove detail
     *
     * @param \SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimateDetail $detail
     */
    public function removeDetail(\SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimateDetail $detail)
    {
        $this->details->removeElement($detail);
    }

    /**
     * Get details
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getDetails()
    {
        return $this->details;
    }

}
```

RequestForEstimateDetail:

```
<?php

namespace SourcingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * RequestForEstimateDetail
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="request_for_estimate_detail")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SourcingBundle\Repository\RequestForEstimateDetailRepository")
 */
class RequestForEstimateDetail
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="request_detail_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RequestForEstimate", inversedBy="details")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="request_id", referencedColumnName="request_id")
     */
    private $detail;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductsBundle\Entity\Product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="product_id")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer")
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price_per_unit", type="decimal", precision=2, scale=0)
     */
    private $pricePerUnit;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="shipping_cost", type="decimal", precision=2, scale=0)
     */
    private $shippingCost;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="other_fees", type="decimal", precision=2, scale=0)
     */
    private $otherFees;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set product
     *
     * @param integer $product
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function setProduct($product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    /**
     * Set quantity
     *
     * @param integer $quantity
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function setQuantity($quantity)
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quantity
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    /**
     * Set pricePerUnit
     *
     * @param string $pricePerUnit
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function setPricePerUnit($pricePerUnit)
    {
        $this->pricePerUnit = $pricePerUnit;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pricePerUnit
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPricePerUnit()
    {
        return $this->pricePerUnit;
    }

    /**
     * Set shippingCost
     *
     * @param string $shippingCost
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function setShippingCost($shippingCost)
    {
        $this->shippingCost = $shippingCost;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shippingCost
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getShippingCost()
    {
        return $this->shippingCost;
    }

    /**
     * Set otherFees
     *
     * @param string $otherFees
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function setOtherFees($otherFees)
    {
        $this->otherFees = $otherFees;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get otherFees
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOtherFees()
    {
        return $this->otherFees;
    }

    /**
     * Set requestId
     *
     * @param \SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $requestId
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function setRequestId(\SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $requestId = null)
    {
        $this->requestId = $requestId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get requestId
     *
     * @return \SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate
     */
    public function getRequestId()
    {
        return $this->requestId;
    }

    /**
     * Set productId
     *
     * @param \SourcingBundle\Entity\Product $productId
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function setProductId(\SourcingBundle\Entity\Product $productId = null)
    {
        $this->productId = $productId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get productId
     *
     * @return \SourcingBundle\Entity\Product
     */
    public function getProductId()
    {
        return $this->productId;
    }

    /**
     * Set detail
     *
     * @param \SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $detail
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function setDetail(\SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $detail = null)
    {
        $this->detail = $detail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get detail
     *
     * @return \SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate
     */
    public function getDetail()
    {
        return $this->detail;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->detail = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add detail
     *
     * @param \SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $detail
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function addDetail(\SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $detail)
    {
        $this->detail[] = $detail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove detail
     *
     * @param \SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $detail
     */
    public function removeDetail(\SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $detail)
    {
        $this->detail->removeElement($detail);
    }

}
```

RequestForEstimateDetailType:

```
<?php
namespace SourcingBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class RequestForEstimateDetailType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('quantity');  
        $builder->add('pricePerUnit'); 
        $builder->add('shippingCost'); 
        $builder->add('otherFees'); 
        $builder->add('product', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'                 =>  'ProductsBundle\Entity\Product',
                'choice_label' => function ($product) {
                    return $product->getName();
                }

        ));



    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimateDetail',
        ));
    }
}
```

RequestForEstimateController:

```
<?php

namespace SourcingBundle\Controller;

use SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate;
use SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimateDetail;
use SourcingBundle\Form\Type\RequestForEstimateType;
use SourcingBundle\Form\Type\RequestForEstimateDetailType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class RequestForEstimateController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("sourcing/request-for-estimate/create", name="request_for_estimate_create")
     */
    public function addRequest(Request $request)
    {

        $RequestForEstimate = new RequestForEstimate();
        $form = $this->createForm(RequestForEstimateType::class, $RequestForEstimate);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $request = $form->getData();

            $request->setStatus(0);
            $request->setupdateTime(new \DateTime());
            $request->setcreateTime(new \DateTime());
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($request);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('request_for_estimate_view_all');
        }


        return $this->render('sourcing/requestforestimate/create.html.twig', array(
           'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));



    }
    /**
     * @Route("sourcing/request-for-estimate", name="request_for_estimate_view_all")
     */
    public function viewProducts()
    {
        $requests = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('SourcingBundle:RequestForEstimate')->findAll();

        if (!$requests) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No requests found '
            );
        }
        return $this->render('sourcing/requestforestimate/view.html.twig', array(
           'requests' => $requests
        ));

    }
}
```

Product entity:

```
<?php

namespace ProductsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ProductsBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="create_time", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $createTime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="update_time", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $updateTime;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    protected $description;

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function setProduct($product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param integer $status
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set createTime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createTime
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setCreateTime($createTime)
    {
        $this->createTime = $createTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createTime
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreateTime()
    {
        return $this->createTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set updateTime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updateTime
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setUpdateTime($updateTime)
    {
        $this->updateTime = $updateTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updateTime
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdateTime()
    {
        return $this->updateTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like a lazy-loading-issue.

Doctrine2 is lazy-loading if you don't configure something else, that means your `$requests = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SourcingBundle:RequestForEstimate')->findAll();` won't return real `product` or `details` objects, but Proxy objects.

What you should do, is to prefetch the relations data, like so:

```
$requests = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SourcingBundle:RequestForEstimate')
    ->createQueryBuilder('requests')
    ->select('request, detail, product')
    ->leftJoin('requests.detail', 'detail')
    ->leftJoin('requests.product', 'product')
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Hope you get an idea and it helped ;)

Comment: Thank you for your response & pointing out the issue. Would any of these work: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html   ?

Comment: Also, I followed your direction and I created a custom query and when I do dump(detail.product) it actually shows values but when I do {{detail.product.name}} I get an error again. How do I access these properties?